# Can I use bulk_create on models with primary keys being AutoFields without making the data inconsistent?

Tags: django, database

From Django documentation of `bulk_create`:

> If the model’s primary key is an `AutoField` it does not retrieve and set the primary key attribute, as `save()`
>   does, unless the database backend supports it (currently PostgreSQL).

Well I'm not using Postgres.

Am I to understand that if my model's pimary key is an `AutoField` then `bulk_create` will insert rows to the database with empty primary key column? I suppose that having in a table rows with no value for primary key is a straight way to problems, since it breaks the invariant that each row must have a primary key set and no two rows may have the same primary key, right?

Can I solve this problem by manually setting the primary key like this when I know the table to be empty before the `bulk_create`?

```
Person.objects.bulk_create([
    Person(name='John', surname='Doe', pk=1),
    Person(name='Mary', surname='Sue', pk=2)
])
```

Will it not create problems with further insertion of objects? For example, if after the above statement I do:

```
Person.objects.create(name='Donald', surname='Duck')
```

Will Donald Duck's primary key be correctly set to `3`? Or will it be incorrectly set to `1`?

Can I force the primary key counter for the new objects to be set to an arbitrary value (like, in this case, '3')?

If I set the primary key to a correct value and manually add correct primary key values for the rows inserted with `bulk_create` – will I be able to use `bulk_create` without endangering table consistency in the database?

Comment: I accept your question that it will continue be important, even after you probably come to know answers to many sub-questions. Did you read any of answers here? I have overwritten my answer now to be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your database rows will always have a primary key value. Django wouldn't be able to violate that constraint even if it wanted to.

When Django performs a bulk create and you don't explicitly set the primary key, the primary key is generated by the database. To set the new primary key value on the model instance, Django needs a way to map the newly created primary keys to the model instances. At the moment, only Postgres supports this on bulk inserts. If you perform a bulk create on a different database, the model instances won't have a primary key set, but the rows in the database will have one.

If you need to know the primary key values for the bulk created objects on other databases, you need to explicitly set the value before you save them. Depending on your database, the auto-increment primary key may or may not take into account the inserted values. If it doesn't take them into account, you can use the [`sqlsequencereset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#sqlsequencereset) management command to generate the SQL that will reset the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** fundamentally.

Your approach is relative easy if only one Django process is running, but assigning a new primary key from Django application could be problematic if more Django processes run **concurrently**. There would be a risk that two processes read the same highest available primary key, the assign pks to objects, run bulk_create and consequently one of processes fails with exception:
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: app_mymodel.id`
Data **integrity** is ensured, but not **feasibility**. No row is created, even if only a single conflict exists.

Some simple safe solutions how to get or know primary keys after bulk_create exist  for **many use cases**:

A) Very frequent case of `bulk_create` is to create **one** new object **with more related** objects, e.g. an invoice or order and their line items. The invoice ID and child object line number assigned by application are enough to unambiguously identify the new items. Primary keys of these items are not necessary to be read immediately until you create more levels of child objects.

B) A **natural unique identifier** exists like book ISBN and no items with the same identifier should exist in the database. It can be used to bulk read primary keys after bulk_create.

C) A global pseudorandom **primary key of type [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)** can be safe assigned by Django automatically. Such identifiers are much longer than a sequential id. It must be long due to "Birthdate paradox". The UUID is unique enough even between servers.

D) bulk_create items related to a simple **log item** of the request, with fields who and when created the items. A primary key of the log is useful to easier identify and solve a possible new duplicity after bulk_create. It is similar to case A)

E) Turn the web server **offline** or single process  while running bulk_create with pre-filled pk.

(You probably don't want to implement a try-except code wrapped by a loop to elevate the tried pk after fail, until success. Race condition related bugs can not be easily tested and debugged. Same database backends and transaction modes can be especially problematic with try-except around integrity error. The solutions on top are resistant.)